# Perl and Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: perl, selenium, automated-tests

EDITED AGAIN

I have a server on AWS somewhere in Northern Virginia and this is my monitoring server. I ssh into this Ubuntu server from another State to do system administration. I want to do web automation tests on this server which will test a web application on the Internet hitting a URL and verify that I can selenium test a login and authenticate successfully. This  server is on an AWS cloud I'm not quite sure which Perl module to use since I'm accessing it remotely.

There are two CPAN modules: Selenium::Remote::Driver and WWW::Selenium. I have tried both and they are giving me issues. And I really don't know which is appropriate for my scenario. When I use Selenium::Remote::Driver, I get the following error:

```
Selenium server did not return proper status at     /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 401.
```

When I use WWW::Selenium, I get this error:

```
Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser
```

I was able to launch firefox manually from the AWS monitoring server by exporting the DISPLAY but it was really slow. I have heard that I can use a headless browser but I would have to export the DISPLAY by:

```
export DISPLAY=:5
```

But remember, I'm sshing into this AWS/Selenium server from my desktop so I'm assuming I use the above command on the AWS/Selenium Server while I'm ssh into it from my desktop? Actually, at this point, I'm not sure I'm doing here.  Can somebody help?

Comment: so your port is 443 in your example...

Comment: `remote_server_addr` is supposed to be a hostname or an IP, not a URL.

Comment: If you call `$driver->debug_on()`, that will trigger behavior that prints out responses from the remote server. That may contain some helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this type of questions is that the variety of configurations and binaries in your setup might be so broad that the it is hard to actually provide a straight and correct answer for YOUR SETUP. 
This answer has the following assumptions:

- you have downloaded the selenium-server-standalone.jar into /usr/lib/
- you have jdk 1.8 ( run the `java -version` in the shell
- you have installed and configured the xvfb-run ( it is a fight on it's own )
  So :

```

```
 # ssh to your server , obs the -X !
 ssh -X user-name@server-name

 # start the selenium-server-standalone on the server
 xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/lib/selenium-server-standalone.jar &

  # one liner test - this is one veery long one 
 perl -e 'use strict ; use warnings ; use Data::Printer ; my $host="127.0.0.1"; use Selenium::Remote::Driver;my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( "browser_name" =>"chrome", "error_handler" => sub { print $_[1]; croak 'goodbye'; }, "remote_server_addr" => "$host","port"=> "4444");$driver->debug_on();$driver->get("http://www.google.com"); print $driver->get_title();$driver->quit();' &
```

```

Here is the code in the one-liner as a perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Carp ;
use Data::Printer ;
 use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

my $host="127.0.0.1";
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
    "browser_name" =>"chrome"
  , "error_handler" => sub { print $_[1]; croak 'goodbye' ; }
  , "remote_server_addr" => "$host"
  , "port"=> "4444") ;
$driver->debug_on() ;
$driver->get("http://www.google.com");
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

The output should look something like: 
```

```
        Prepping get
        Executing get
        REQ: POST, http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b/url, {"url":"http://www.google.com"}
        RES: {"sessionId":"ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b","status":0,"value":null}

        Prepping getTitle
        Executing getTitle
        REQ: GET, http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b/title, {}
        RES: {"sessionId":"ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b","status":0,"value":"Google"}

        GooglePrepping quit
        Executing quit
        REQ: DELETE, http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b, {}
        RES: {"sessionId":"ddb9c2575ab026cdb8c640bdc554181b","status":0,"value":null}
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use warnings;
use strict;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

my $host = "10.10.1.1"; //Enter your server IP in this place
my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver('remote_server_addr' =>  $host,
                                           'port' => '4444', 
                                           'auto_close' => 0);
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
```